# How to build a Mac OS X Installer Package from these files?

Tags: xcode, macos, package, packagemaker, pkg-file

Already tried many ways: pkgbuild, productbuild, PackageMaker, Packages application...

The structure of the flat package that I want to build:

```
Distribution - xml script
MacBookPro2011EFIUpdate.pkg - flat package
Resources - resources folder, contains language localizations
```

Flat package information:

```
id="com.apple.pkg.MacBookPro2011EFIUpdate" version="2.7.0.0.1.1330468277"
```

For example, my failure with productbuild:

```
productbuild: error: Cannot copy package "MacBookPro2011EFIUpdate.pkg" into product.
(Bundle-style package "MacBookPro2011EFIUpdate.pkg" is not supported.)
```

Please, try to build the installer package from these files: [Link](http://www.mediafire.com/?w7ib3vilwzjjzz9)
And, if you succeed, please tell how you did that!

Answer (score 11):

The correct command to use is indeed `productbuild`, but it does only work on Flat packages, as the error indicates.  And your `MacBookPro2011EFIUpdate.pkg` is a Bundle-style package: easy to tell the difference in that Bundle-style packages are a directory, where as Flat packages are a xar archive.

To get what you want, first convert the Bundle-style package into a Flat package:
`pkgutil --flatten MacBookPro2011EFIUpdate.pkg FlatMacBookPro2011EFIUpdate.pkg`

Then generate a new distribution file that uses this new Flat package:
`productbuild --package FlatMacBookPro2011EFIUpdate.pkg --synthesize newdist.dist`

Copy your scripts and resource entries from your Distribution file into newdist.dist.  Then build your final package:
`productbuild --resources Resources/ --distribution newdist.dist MyCoolPackage.pkg`

Comment: Hi, I have a mac app file and also created its package file using "productbuild" namely hello.app and hello.pkg. Now I wish to add a license agreement to that package. for this, I have created distribution.xml from my hello.app file now I wish to include this in package but get error as not allowed.

Comment: productbuild --synthesize --product "hello.app/Contents/Info.plist" --package hello.app distribution.xml

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <installer-gui-script minSpecVersion="1">
        <title>My Example Application</title>
       <license file="LICENSE.html"/>
         <readme file="README.html"/>
    …
    …
  </installer-gui-script>

Comment: productbuild --distribution distribution.xml hello.pkg